# synchronized thread not implementing sleep

Tags: java, multithreading, automated-tests, sleep, web-api-testing

I was encountering a race condition on some of my API tests, where I wanted to check for the existence of a user after calling a create endpoint.
I created a class that checks if valid data is returned and if not retires for up to four times, this works fine locally, but I have noticed that when it's running in a pipeline it doesn't execute the thread.sleep commands.

**Class created to get around the race condition**

```
  public static Object commonExistenceQuery(Object endpoint) throws InterruptedException {
        int Counter = 0;
        Object ID = "";
        Object falseCheck = "false";

        synchronized (ID) {
            System.out.println("attempting to obtain Id for endpoint");
            ID = endpoint;
            while (ID == falseCheck) {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                ID = endpoint;
                Counter++;
                System.out.println("Id not yet obtained, retrying attempt " + Counter + " of 4");
                if (Counter == 4|| ID != falseCheck) {
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (Counter == 4) {
                throw new ArithmeticException("ID was never obtained for endpoint, ensure successfully created");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("successfully called endpoint and returned a valid ID of " + endpoint);
                return ID;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Class that finds user (called in ID=endpoint)**

```
    public Object findUser(Object name) throws IOException {

        JSONObject failure = new JSONObject();
        failure.put("check","false");

        Map request = new HashMap();
        Map body = new HashMap();

        body.put("name", name);
        body.put("business", "claims");
        body.put("unit", 10);
        request.put("body", body);
        request.put("callback", "true");

        Map findUser = run(userEndpoint.find, request,false);

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(findUser);
        JSONObject getId = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
        if (getId == null){
            getId = failure;
            // we need to convert the null to a json object in the result of a failure, to avoid a null pointer exception
            System.out.println("failure to locate user ID, returning ID of "+getId.get("check"));
            return getId.get("check");
        }
        else
        {
            return getId.get("id");
        }
    }
```

any ideas why the thread.sleep(1000) might not be working, or ways to improve the code would be welcomed

Comment: `ID == falseCheck` use `equals`

Comment: Modifying the object you're synchronizing is likely to cause extreme chaos.

Comment: @LouisWasserman, I reckon that most experienced Java developers would understand exactly what you mean. Beginners, maybe not so much. `ID = endpoint` does _not_ modify an object. It assigns a variable. One of the biggest hurdles for beginners learning Java is to learn the difference between objects and variables.

Comment: Agree with other comments + answers, also want to add that it's really, really scary to see `Thread.sleep()`. There are so many ways that the timing won't work out right, and you'll have almost no chance of finding the cause.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple significant errors here. Your code is basically a weirdly loaded dice.

> ```java
> String ID = "";
> synchronized (ID) {
> ```

You synchronize on **the object**, not **the variable**. So, you're asking the `""` object to hold a lock. Which 'works', but is crazy - do not lock on strings. You need to make a lock object and use the same object for all the synchronized blocks you want to 'gate' so that only one thread can run. In other words, `synchronized(x) {CODE}` means that that thread will wait until it can obtain the lock on the object that the `x` variable points at. If it isn't locked by anything else, it will get the lock and run. Otherwise it waits until its free.

> ```java
> Object falseCheck = "false";
> ```

What in the blazes is this? Java has booleans. Also, `falseCheck` is a crazy name.

> ```java
> ID == falseCheck
> ```

`==` between 2 objects does a reference identity check which isn't what you wanted here, you want an equality check; that'd be `ID.equals(falseCheck)`. Not that its relevant, this obviously needs to be `boolean` stuff.

> any ideas why the thread.sleep(1000) might not be working

Your code doesn't work, there's all sorts of crazy stuff you've done here that you haven't tested, and your first instinct is: "This well documented core library function must somehow be broken". You should assume library functions aren't broken and do precisely what their documentation says they do. If you think they don't work, you're 99.9999% of the time wrong; it's your code that is broken.

> ```java
> JSONObject
> ```

Crappy API; don't use that. Jackson or GSON.